# Azure Log Analytics parse json

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql

I have a query which results in a few columns but one of the columns, I am parsing JSON to retrieve the object value but there are multiple entries in it I want each entry in JSON to retrieve in a loop and display.

Below is the query,

```
let forEach_table = AzureDiagnostics
| where Parameters_LOAD_GROUP_s contains 'LOAD(AUTO)';
let ParentPlId = '';
let ParentPlName = '';
let commonKey = '';
forEach_table
| where Category == 'PipelineRuns'
| extend pplId = parse_json(Predecessors_s)[0].PipelineRunId, pplName = parse_json(Predecessors_s)[0].PipelineName
| extend dbMapName = tostring(parse_json(Parameters_getMetadataList_s)[0].dbMapName)
| summarize count(runId_g) by Resource, Status = status_s, Name=pipelineName_s, Loadgroup = Parameters_LOAD_GROUP_s, dbMapName, Parameters_LOAD_GROUP_s, Parameters_getMetadataList_s, pipelineName_s, Category, CorrelationId, start_t, end_t, TimeGenerated
| project ParentPL_ID = ParentPlId, ParentPL_Name = ParentPlName, LoadGroup_Name = Loadgroup, Map_Name = dbMapName, Status,Metadata = Parameters_getMetadataList_s, Category,  CorrelationId, start_t, end_t
| project-away ParentPL_ID, ParentPL_Name, Category, CorrelationId
```

here in the above code,

```
extend dbMapName = tostring(parse_json(Parameters_getMetadataList_s)[0].dbMapName)
```

I am retrieving 0th element as default but I would like to retrieve all elements in sequence can somebody suggest me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

[bag_keys()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bagkeysfunction) is just what you need.

For example, take a look at this query:

```
datatable(myjson: dynamic) [
   dynamic({"a": 123, "b": 234, "c": 345}),
   dynamic({"dd": 123, "ee": 234, "ff": 345})
]
| project keys = bag_keys(myjson)
```

Its output is:

```
|---------|
| keys    |
|---------|
| [       |
|   "a",  |
|   "b",  |
|   "c"   |
| ]       |
|---------|
| [       |
|   "dd", |
|   "ee", |
|   "ff"  |
| ]       |
|---------|
```

If you want to have every key in a separate row, use [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator), like this:

```
datatable(myjson: dynamic) [
   dynamic({"a": 123, "b": 234, "c": 345}),
   dynamic({"dd": 123, "ee": 234, "ff": 345})
]
| project keys = bag_keys(myjson)
| mv-expand keys
```

The output of this query will be:

```
|------|
| keys |
|------|
| a    |
| b    |
| c    |
| dd   |
| ee   |
| ff   |
|------|
```

Comment: Hi Slavik, Thanks for the suggestion but I have a couple of questions for the above suggestion. So for my scenario, Parameters_getMetadataList_s contains all mapnames which I need in a column but they are not fixed, for every load group it differs so this means I cannot create a data table for that particular one right.

Comment: You don't need to use `datatable` - it's just something I use to provide examples, instead of real tables. So `bag_keys` and `mv-expand` should do what you're looking for. If you need more help, please update the question and provide sample input (in `datatable` format), and the output you expect to see, and ping me by adding a comment notifying that you updated the question.

Comment: Hi Slavik, Yes I got it thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

extend and mv-expand methods help in resolving this kind of scenario.

Solution:
extend rows = parse_json(Parameters_getMetadataList_s)
| mv-expand rows
| project Parameters_LOAD_GROUP_s,rows